# Avoid bitmap from being recycled android

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap, android-viewpager

i have two async task one of them download the image and the other one add blur effect on it but my problem is that in the `onPostExecute` callback of the download Task i want to put the bitmap in an ImageView and then pass it to second Task to apply blur effect on it but sometimes i get

```
trying to use a recycled bitmap
```

i have searched alot on this problem but i didn't find a clear solution to avoid this problem specially that i use this image in a fragment of view pager this is my code

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        Bitmap bitmap=result;
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        if(bitmap!=null && !bitmap.isRecycled()){
            Bitmap bb=bitmap;

        new blurTask().execute(bb);}
    }
```

and this my complete fragment code

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
    int page;
    String img;
    // ImageView blured;
    String[] checkblur;
    int size;
    Boolean onCreateViewCalled = false;
    ImageView blur;
    ImageView imageView;

        public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(int page, String img, int size) {
            ScreenSlidePageFragment fragmentFirst = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("someInt", page);
            args.putString("img", img);
            args.putInt("size", size);
            fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
            return fragmentFirst;
        }

        // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
            img = getArguments().getString("img");
            size = getArguments().getInt("size");
            checkblur = new String[size];
            onCreateViewCalled = false;
        }

        public void ChangeAlpha(float alpha) {
            System.out.println(alpha);
            blur.setAlpha(alpha);

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = (View) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

           imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            blur = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.blur);
            //Glide.with(this).load(img).into(imageView);
            new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(img);
        return v;
        }
     class blurTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Integer, BitmapDrawable> {
            Bitmap image;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected BitmapDrawable doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                image = params[0];


                Bitmap b = Blur.blurBitmap(image, getActivity());
                final BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);


                return ob;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(BitmapDrawable blur1) {
                // Do whatever you need with the string, you can update your UI from here
                // blured.setBackground(blur);
                if (blur1 != null)
                    System.out.println("yryryryry");
                blur.setBackground(blur1);
            }


        }
        class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            ImageView bmImage;

            public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
                this.bmImage = bmImage;
            }

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String urldisplay = urls[0];
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return mIcon11;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(result));
                new blurTask().execute(Bitmap.createBitmap(bmImage));

            }
        }
    }
```

so i get the image then the blur effect appear but when i try to swipe to the next viewpager page i get this error
any help?
Thanks.

Comment: I made bad experience with bitmap and copy them. Why you copy at first the `result` in `bitmap` and after that again in `bb` ?

Comment: `Just scaled down your images`. That's the solution.

Comment: becuase i have framelayout which contain two images one for the original on for the blur image

Comment: @MD could explain your solution ?

Comment: [Mange Bitmap in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid `trying to use a recycled bitmap` by copying original bitmap to new bitmap before processing. Try this

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    new blurTask().execute(Bitmap.createBitmap(result));
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks @Arkar but could this solution come with bad experience with the performance?

Comment: I'm still getting same problem when i navigate between pager fragment

Comment: @Tony Got error only when swipe to the next viewpager page ?

Comment: I think the problem is in pager adapter. Which adapter do you use ? PagerAdapter or FragmentPagerAdapter ?

Comment: Fragment pager adapter if u want i can paste adapter code

Comment: I've test with two async and fragment pager adpater. It's fine. Let me know your image Blur library. May be recycling bitmap is in that..

Comment: ya it's rare two happen i have around 15 fragment

Comment: it's just one class i have found it its called stackblur

Comment: yes @Arkar you are right the problem was from the blur code i have changed it and the problem solved

Comment: Glad to hear that ! :)